# ListView and ScrollView not showing correctly

Tags: android, listview, layout, scrollview

I'm having problems with a layout in wich I have two buttons (working fine) and a **listview wrapped by a scrollview**.

The problem is that the list is shown but I can only see one element, I can scroll but the rest of the screen is wasted and I want the listview to be displayed as big as it can be.

Here is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Enviar" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layhoriz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_arriba"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Arriba" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_salir_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salir" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add the java code you are using to populate the view, your problem should be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a ListView element without scrollview, the scroll works on the ListView when the number of elements are more than the elements displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the duplicate questions for listview inside scrollview...

[Android ListView rows in ScrollView not fully displayed - clipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709411/android-listview-rows-in-scrollview-not-fully-displayed-clipped)

[ListView inside ScrollView is not scrolling on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android)

[ListView inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415011/listview-inside-a-scrollview)

Comment: Ok, the problem was that the listview is already scrollable, so I don't need to wrap it with any scrollview

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the scroll view over the list view

Answer (score 0):

Its not a best practice to put any vertically scrollable viewgroup inside another vetical scrolling viewgroup/container.

Have a look a [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android?rq=1)

If you anyway want to achieve it, look at the answer given in the [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/11554684#11554684).

Answer (score 0):

You don't put Auto expanding views ( like `ListView`) in a `ScrollView`.

`ScrollView` is set to expand for its contents and provide scrolling, it has no height/width of its own set. So, its child view should not try to `match_parent`.

Mark the `ListView` to have a fixed height.

I recommend watching [this google presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html), about `ListView`s.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` will scroll its contents automatically, so there is no need to use a `ScrollView`.