# View doesnt show all the items

Tags: android, listview, view, android-linearlayout, dimension

So, I have a layout with CardView for some things. When i try to add listview to one of those CardViews, it just shows one item. I checked in other activities, it is showing all the items that need to be shown, but for this one it doesnt. I know it has to do something with layout height and dimensions, but I cant figure. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Veceras"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vecerasTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="O lokalu"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/oLokaluTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Meni"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/meniLista"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rezervisiStoFloatinAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/r"

    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

for the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view this question, as the problem of nesting a `ListView` within a `ScrollView` has already been addressed.

[Android ListView rows in ScrollView not fully displayed - clipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709411/android-listview-rows-in-scrollview-not-fully-displayed-clipped)